# How can I inject custom rendering code into a Cell?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cells, rails-cells

I've created a Cell that renders a table view of data and I'd like to reuse it for other table views. For each row of that data, I'd like to have some unique elements mixed with the standard columns. Right now, a simplified portion version of my Cell's `show.html.slim` looks like:

```
- users.each do |user|
  tr
    / A column unique to User
    td
      = link_to_if current_user == user, "Groups", user_groups_path(user)
    / Common code that can be shared across other tables
    td user.name
```

I'd like to be able to extract the User-specific code from this level and inject it from above. The [Cells documentation](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) states:

> If in doubt, encapsulate nested parts of your view into a separate cell. You can use the #cell method in your cell to instantiate a nested cell.

However, it's difficult to simply instantiate a new Cell (*edit: within the table cell*):

1. I need to know what cell to create.
2. I need to be able to pass in information from the parent cell (`user` in my example).
3. I need to be able to pass in information specific to the child cell (`current_user` in my example).

What options exist for injecting this type of partial rendering into a Cell? Are any of them generally preferred solutions?

Comment: Are you looking to render a partial? I am unclear on the overall question especially when it pertains to a table.

Comment: My use of a table is just to provide a concrete example. I'd be happy to render a partial, so long as I can inform the Cell what partial to render (different contexts will have different partials) and I can provide partial-specific information without having to edit my general Cell code.

Comment: partials accept locals which would be specific to the partial. the conditional logic could be controlled in the current view or in a partial that renders partials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just defining some methods on my cell that accept blocks

```
class DataTableCell < Cell::ViewModel
  def row_prefix(&blk)
    @_row_prefix = blk
  end

  def render_row_prefix(item)
    return unless @_row_prefix
    @_row_prefix.call(item).call
  end
end
```

Whenever I want to render the `DataTableCell`, I provide a block like:

```
cell = cell(:data_table)
cell.row_prefix do |item|
  cell(:users_row_prefix, user: item, current_user: current_user)
end
```

Inside my cell, I can just call `render_row_prefix(row_item)`.

I'm not in live with this solutions, as it can be kind of heavyweight, but it does work.